# How to create a column in Parse using code

Tags: java, android-studio, parse-platform

I want to create a new column to store an array list in Parse, but I am unable to create the column (without using the dashboard). It needs to be created in the default "User" class. I've tried creating a Parse object in the user class and I tried querying for the column(hoping that if it doesn't find it, it will create it). It needs to be a column that can store an array list. I am not getting any errors in my code so I am unsure what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is with the .NET API, but I suspect the principle is the same.

Parse will not create a new column simply from a read; you must set a value in at least one instance, and save it to the DB. This will create the column. Previously existing rows will contain "Undefined" for the new column value, and will not contain a key for the column.

My practice has been to derive types for my various ParseObjects. One thing this affords is that I can wrap the check for the key in my property getters, and set a default value if it is missing.

A caveat: (I'm speaking C#-ese here, so you'll have to do a mental translation) When you derive from ParseObject, you decorate the class with a ParseClassName attribute that defines the name for the document type in your database that your class is bound to. However, Parse already has a derived type, ParseUser, and when you derive from that, you must bind to the predefined "_User" class. (This is true for "_Session" and "_Role" also.)